# How to run cron.php on linux server using php file

Tags: php, cron

I want to run cron.php file from my php code, Abc.php is my php file from which I have to run cron.php.I tried include in php but not working.Also I tried exec method to execute php script but it also not worked for me.

Working from web browser by simply putting url of cron.php in browser and also working from command line on linux server by using php cron.php and pressing enter key.

Comment: define "not working". Be more specific in what is going wrong like adding code and error logs

Comment: no error.actually not running cron.php script by using include and exec method.  I am using moodle